# How to append a character after N patterns at each line in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, append

How can I insert a ',' after the 2nd character ',' at each line ?

I want the following :

input.txt

```
a,b,c,d,e
e,f,g,
h,,i
```

output.txt

```
a,b,,c,d,e
e,f,,g
h,,,i
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

input

```
$ cat input 
a,b,c,d,e
e,f,g,
h,,i
```

using sed like:

```
$ N=2
$ cat input | sed "s/,/&,/${N}"
a,b,,c,d,e
e,f,,g,
h,,,i

$ N=3
$ cat input | sed "s/,/&,/${N}"
a,b,c,,d,e
e,f,g,,
h,,i
```

you can change the N.

---

```
s/pattern/replacement/flags
```

Substitute the replacement string for the pattern.
The value of flags in substitute function is zero or more of the following:

```
N       Make the substitution only for the N'th occurrence 
g       Make the substitution for all
```

for function `s/,/&,/${N}`, it is find the N'th comma and replace it with two commas (An ampersand (`&`) appearing in the replacement is replaced by the pattern string). And ${N} just is a variable.

BTW, you need to escape the special character double quote if you want to insert ,""

Answer (score 3):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$3=OFS $3}1' file
a,b,,c,d,e
e,f,,g,
h,,,i
```

after second `,` is the third field.  Prefix the third field with `,` and print.

Or, making the column number a parameter and writing delimiter once.

```
$ awk -F, -v c=3 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {$c=OFS $c}1' file
```

This can be read as "insert a new column at position 3".  Note that this will also work, adding the 6th column, which will be hard to replicate with `sed`.

```
$ awk -F, -v c=6 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {$c=OFS $c}1' file

a,b,c,d,e,,
e,f,g,,,,
h,,i,,,,
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^([^,]*,[^,]*,)(.*)/\1,\2/' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
a,b,c,d,e
e,f,g,
h,,i

% sed -E 's/^([^,]*,[^,]*,)(.*)/\1,\2/' file.txt
a,b,,c,d,e
e,f,,g,
h,,,i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` like this:

```
sed 's/^[^,]*,[^,]*/&,/' file

a,b,,c,d,e
e,f,,g,
h,,,i
```